# Void function doesn't print

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code to print values using function and the program doesn't print anything and I don't know why. I know void function don't return any value so I put cout inside the function and I call is correctly

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Print(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        if (n%i == 0){
            cout << i << ' ';
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
    
int main(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    Print(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see what's going on as it executes?

Comment: Hint: What do you think happens to code in a function after you call `return`?

Comment: @tadman , please help I don't see the problem ?!

Comment: Step through in a debugger and you will *immediately* become enlightened. If you compiled with more warnings (e.g. `-Wall`) you might also be made aware of the problem.

Comment: Quick sidenote: The lower half of your `main` is dead code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your loop from 1 in `Print` function. You can not mod a number with 0. Division by zero is not allowed.

Comment: That's not it either. Look more closely.

Comment: @tadman Actually, this is one part of the solution too as dividing by zero will immediately break the program.

Comment: @HyunIKim That's also an issue, but the spurious `return` is also a problem.

Comment: What to look at? He used `return 0` after `PrintDom(x);` in `main` function. So Only `PrintDom(x);` function will run. But this function starts a loop from 0 and tries to mod a number with 0. So, it produces an error and closes automatically.

Comment: Right, his question was that he's seeing NOTHING, so starting the loop from 1 will be the first issue to resolve. At least he will see something after the fix.
I assume that `return` problem is something that he could figure out if he starts to see something from the console.

Comment: @HyunIKim I agree. I would do the same. I also would check if the initial function works properly first by closing the program after the initial function.

Comment: @RiasatAliAkash , Thank you it worked. It's true that I put that return or purpose cause I knew that the problem was in print function but I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program, it wont print anything. You have to enter a number first, then press Enter/Return, and then it should print something.

Assuming you do this and it still does not print, that will be because your `Print` has a loop that starts from `i = 0`, and you then do `n % i`. Doing the modulo `%` operation with a right-hand-side operand of `0` is not going to work. Start the loop from `i = 1` or something else `>0`.

Lastly, your program will terminate in `main` at the `return 0;` right after the first `Print`. This means that most of your `main` won't actually be executed. This is probably intentional, but keep that in mind.

Fix these issues and make sure you enter a number into your program when it runs that is valid, like `12`, and it should print something.